# Usecases that really need Hibernate HQL over JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hql, jpql

I know JPQL is a subset of HQL.

Are there any practical usecases (please give examples) that really need HQL specific features to be used (that means it is impossible or considerably difficult with JPQL) to implement them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conclude that there is no practical usecase that is impossible or considerably difficult to implement only with JPQL (without using HQL)

Answer (score 4):

Each time you want to use one of the expressions/functions listed in [the HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions), and which is not supported by JPQL :

- second, minute, etc.
- user additions to the dialect
- etc.

Comment: Since JPA 2 there is also case and coalesce in JPQL.

Comment: I understand and agree with your point, but to nitpick, case is available in jpa 2.

Comment: @Mikko Maunu The above is not an answer to my question, I just needed a usecase (if one exists).

Comment: @MISS_DUKE, if "above" refers to my comment, you are right. It is not answer, it is comment to an answer.

Comment: @Mikko Maunu Sorry for the misunderstanding, I referred the answer by JB Nizet